# Count each unique values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using SQL in MS-Access. I would like to count each unique value from the column **code** in my table.

that's my table:

```
| **code** |   **description**      |      **date**    | **level** |  
|  AAA     |       example          |    01/01/2020    |     x     |
|  AAA     |       example          |    02/05/2020    |     z     |
|  BBB     |       example          |    09/09/2020    |     y     |
|  CCC     |       example          |    12/10/2020    |     z     |
```

expected result:

```
    | **code** |   **description**      |      **date**    | **level** | **count** |
    |  AAA     |       example          |    01/01/2020    |     x     |    2      |
    |  AAA     |       example          |    02/05/2020    |     z     |    2      |
    |  BBB     |       example          |    09/09/2020    |     y     |    1      |
    |  CCC     |       example          |    12/10/2020    |     z     |    1      |
```

I know the following query works:

```
SELECT code, count(*) FROM table GROUP BY code;
```

But I wanted the select to count the **code** column, and show all the other columns as well. I created this query:

```
SELECT code, description, date, level, count(code) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY code, description, date, level;
```

But it shows all lines in the "count" column as 1 (even those with repeated values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show all rows (no aggregation). You want to show an additional column with an aggregation. You can do this aggregation in a subquery.

```
SELECT
  code, description, date, level, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table AS t2 WHERE t2.code = t.code) AS code_count
FROM table AS t
ORDER BY code, date;
```

As to your own query: You are pseudo aggregating. As all rows are different from each other, your `GROUP BY` on all columns keeps the original rows. Then you count how many rows you find in each "group" which is always 1 (the row itself).